# How know if Intent ACTION_TIME_CHANGED is coming from direct user interaction

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How know if Intent ACTION_TIME_CHANGED is coming from direct user interaction.

I tried check the flag FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND from Intent, but always come 0, even if the Intent was triggered by sync network.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t really know if it works, I can´t try this at the moment, but there is the Settings API with that You can get some informations. I am not sure about if You can read this without root, but give it a try.

```
  String isAutoTime = Settings.System.getString(
  getContentResolver(), 
  Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);

  boolean autoTimeEnabled = false; 

  if(isAutoTime.equals("1")){

    autoTimeEnabled = true;

  }
  //usually You don´t need this else statement, because the boolean is
  //created as a flase boolean. Just want to show how it works
  else if(isAutoTime.equals("0")){

    autoTimeEnabled=false;

  }
```

Since API 17, `Settings.System.AUTO_TIME` is deprecated, so You have to take `Settins.Global.AUTO_TIME` and `Settings.Global.getString()`

Like described in the API 17 in Settings.Global:

**Applications can read these but are not allowed to write**

So I think it should be no problem to detect if fetching the time by network is enabled. If it works, You could handle Your BroadCast with ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and when the time is changed, check if this option is enabled in the settings. So You could know if it is changed by the user or system.

Anyway, this is just a thought, I can´t test it if it really works for now, because I have no IDE here.

Comment: Great! I did some tests and works! =) I will test better and then accept the answer as correct. Thank you!!